# Angular: *ngIf tag on Input Element causes it to be undefined. Cannot read value from input field

Tags: html, angular

I'm confused why this error message is being thrown.  I have narrowed down that the problem is using ngIf causes my input field to be undefined.

HTML:

```
<td *ngIf="editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)">
    <input type="text" id="firstNameUpdate" class="form-control" #firstNameUpdate value="{{person.First_Name}}">
</td>
```

Later in my HTML I use the data by passing firstNameUpdate.value into a method, and I recieve the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent]
```

After doing considerable research I very much believe that using *ngIf is causing the Input Field to become undefined, but I do not understand why, or how to fix the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you give more information about  `person` object and the function   `editingModeCheck` please

Comment: Try to print person.First_Name. Check whether it is giving correct value. Put your TS code also where you are getting the related data.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using value on the input and not [(ngModel)]="person.First_Name"

Answer (score 2):

*ngIf removes an element from the DOM if the condition is not met. So yes, it would be undefined. An alternative would be

```
<td [hidden]="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)">
    <input type="text" id="firstNameUpdate" class="form-control" #firstNameUpdate value="{{person.First_Name}}">
</td>
```

That will just set display to none but keep the element in DOM tree

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you! I would upvote but it requires 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `*ngIf` is causing your issue.  When the if check fails for an `*ngIf`, the DOM elements contained within cease to exist in the DOM.  You want to use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf` if you want your DOM element to always exist, but only appear when the `[hidden]` clause is true.

Replace your `*ngIf` statement with `[hidden]` and use the inverse of your `*ngIf` check. i.e. `<td [hidden]="!editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)">`

Comment: Thank you! was an excellent explanation.  I would upvote this as well if I had 15 rep.

Comment: @NickGrover Glad it worked for you.  I'd suggest maybe giving Todd's answer a shot because his answer is the most correct and best practice in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **value** you should be using **ngModel**. Try to change your input code like this:

```
<td *ngIf="editingModeCheck(person.Person_Id)">
    <input [(ngModel)]="person.First_Name" type="text" id="firstNameUpdate" class="form-control" #firstNameUpdate>
</td>
```

Then later in your HTML instead of passing `firstNameUpdate.value` you could just pass `person.First_Name` into your method and it will always be defined.